# Minimum cost maximum flow algorithm with custom cost function

Tags: algorithm, graph, max-flow

What kind of cost functions can be used in minimum cost maximum flow algorithm?

Is it possible to have a cost function similar to:

- if flow on an edge is between [1, X], cost = FixedCost + C1 + flow * cost_per_flow[C1]
- if flow on an edge is between [X + 1, Y], cost = FixedCost + C2 + flow * cost_per_flow[C2]
- etc.

Does this change the algorithm in any way?

Answer (score 1):

You can add up the fixed costs, and remove them from the equation. Then, You split each edge into 2 edges , each with appropriately calculated costs.

Comment: Can you help me understand this for a simple example: consider I have an edge with maximum capacity 10, and if the flow on that edge is <= 5  then the cost is amount_of_flow * 10, if flow is > 5, the cost is amount_of_flow * 20.

Comment: Exchange the edge for 2 parallel edges, each with capacity of 5. first edge has cost per unit equal to 10, the second one has cost per unit equal to 20. This gives cost of pushing 10 units of flow equal to 150.  But as @redoubtable remarked, the problem seems NP-hard in general.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum cost maximum flow algorithm is just a solver for a specific kind of linear program.

What makes linear programs solvable efficiently is convexity: in this case, if you have two feasible flows F and G, then for all t in [0, 1], the flow tF + (1-t)G is feasible and has cost(tF + (1-t)G) ≤ t cost(F) + (1-t) cost(G). For your objective, this basically means FixedCost in [1, X] is 0, C1 ≤ C2, FixedCost in [X + 1, Y] is (C1 - C2)X ≤ 0. That looks something like this:

```
6|        .
5|       .
4|      .
3|     .
2|   .
1| .
0.----------
 0 1   X
```

Probably it is important to you that FixedCost in [1, X] > 0, but this makes the problem NP-hard. A reduction from Steiner tree in graphs is to make the capacity of each edge infinite and cost the weight specified by the Steiner tree problem for the first unit and 0 thereafter. Make one of the k - 1 Steiner terminals a source with capacity k - 1 and the others sinks with capacity 1. Request the cheapest flow of k - 1 units.